# Why does my code to find a cycle in a DG not work correctly?

Tags: python, algorithm, directed-graph

I have the following task about finding a cycle in a directed graph.
https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/2270

Here is my code, it passes 82%. Where can there be inaccuracies here? I did exactly according to the instructions for describing the algorithms.

```
def dfs(start_v, G, Color, path, result):
    Color[start_v] = 1
    for i in G[start_v]:
        if Color[i] is None:
            path.append(i)
            dfs(i, G, Color, path, result)
            path.pop()
            if len(result) > 0:
                return
        elif Color[i] == 1:
            result.extend(path[path.index(i):])
            return
    Color[start_v] = 2


N, M = map(int, input().split())
Graph = [set() for i in range(N + 1)]
Color = [None] * (N + 1)
result = []

for i in range(M):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    Graph[a].add(b)
i = 1
for i in range(N, 0, -1):
    if Color[i] is None:
        dfs(i, Graph, Color, [i], result)
        if len(result) > 0:
            print("YES")
            print(" ".join(map(str, result)))
            break
        else:
            print('NO')
            break
```

Input:
The first line contains two positive integers n and m (1 ≤ n ≤ 105, 1 ≤ m ≤ 105) - the number of vertices and edges in graph respectively. In the next m lines the edges are given. Each edge is described with a pair of numbers - the numbers of initial and final vertex respectively.

Output:
If the graph does not contain the cycle, print "NO", otherwise print "YES" and then the list of vertices in the order of cycle traversal.

Example 1:

```
IN:
6 7
1 2
1 5
2 3
2 4
4 6
6 5
5 2

OUT:
YES
2 4 6 5
```

Example 2:

```
IN:
3 3
1 2
2 3
1 3

OUT:
NO
```

Comment: @mkrieger1, added examples of in/outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code will print "NO" before having iterated all the nodes of the graph. This should not happen *within* the loop, but after. This is important in cases where the first DFS traversal does not reach all nodes, and there is a cycle in the nodes that it did not reach yet. So the cycle will only be detected in a future iteration of the loop.

Here is the correction of that driver code:

```
for i in range(N, 0, -1):
    if Color[i] is None:
        dfs(i, Graph, Color, [i], result)
        if len(result) > 0:
            print("YES")
            print(" ".join(map(str, result)))
            break
else:
    print('NO')
```

The `else` block now belongs to the `for` statement and will only execute when all iterations of the loop were executed without hitting a `break`.